# Dynamic file path in require with webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, webpack, require

This works fine when i manually request the file using `require`, however the moment i use the exact same request, but change the string so that it's split up with variables it fails.

This works great:

```
module.exports = (function() {
    var $svg = require('svg-inline!../../assets/svgs/global/connected.svg');
    console.log($svg);
}());
```

However if I was to do this:

```
module.exports = (function() {
    var $path = '../../assets/svgs/global/';
    var $svg = require('svg-inline!'+$path+'connected.svg');
    console.log($svg);
}());
```

It fails and says inside the console:

`Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "."`

I guess my question is why can't you concatenate strings like i have here?

Comment: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/118

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to look into webpack [context](https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html). Basically when you try to require something that contains an expression, webpack will create a context.
That expression will be treated as a regular expression and it doesn't work as you may expect.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
require(`svg-inline!${$path}connected.svg`)
```

and if you need more variable in your dynamic path try split require:

```js
function getIcon(name) {
 const [category, filename] = name.split(":");

 if (filename) {
  return require(`one_directory/icons/${category}/${filename}.svg`);
 } else {
  return require(`two_directory/icons/${name}.svg`);
 }
}
```